# To disply welcome message every time i log into unix

Tags: linux

i have tried the below code to display login message every time i log into unix,

**etc/motd welcome**

but it didnt work, pls help me with your suggestions.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32435/what-are-the-different-ways-that-a-message-can-be-displayed-to-a-bash-shell-afte

Comment: i tried it but its not working can you tell me exactly the working code.

Comment: It is not working? What is not working. what is in your file `motd` in the `etc` directory under your home directory? (You are hopefully not referring to executing `/etc/motd` (not the beginning `/`), as that would mean you are inaccurate in reporting, and that would not work as that is not an executable). Include your exact commands and (error) output in the question, **not in comments**. Try to get a running command from the commandline first, then you can try to put that in your `~/.profile` or similar.