# How can I set a bash_logout for all users?

Tags: bash, bashrc

I've run into an issue trying to set up a little bit of ASCII art to display upon connection and on logout.

I can do this for one user with .bashrc and with .bash_logout, and set a login MOTD by creating /etc/profile.d/motd.sh, but haven't found a way to set a universal logout MOTD. How can I do this?

I am running CentOS 6.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking.  `motd` is a message ("message of the day", thus `motd`), that is used for announces such as "This machine will be down for scheduled maintenance on Friday between 12:00 and 14:00".  `.bash_logout` is a script.  You can set a `.bash_logout` script for new users by adding it to `/etc/skel`, and you can add commands to `.bash_logout` for existing users with a script.  But (1) it's pointless to print messages from `.bash_logout` (since the shell is going away...), and `.bash_logout` only applies to people who has `bash` as their shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (`man bash`):

> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the files ~/.bash_logout and /etc/bash.bash_logout, if the files exists.

There is [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32435/what-are-the-different-ways-that-a-message-can-be-displayed-to-a-bash-shell-afte) on U&L SE on login messages.

Comment: Only if `#define SYS_BASH_LOGOUT` is uncommented in `config-top.h` when building `bash`. it is commented out by default and not many packagers enable it either.

Comment: `bash` on CentOS 7 has it enabled.

Comment: Works fine for me using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.